# ESP-12 может ли проигрывать музыку mp3?

Tags: android, arduino

Сможет ли [этот зверь](https://ru.aliexpress.com/item/1pcs-Wireless-module-NodeMcu-Lua-WIFI-Internet-of-Things-development-board-based-ESP8266-CP2102-with-pcb/32733851178.html?spm=a2g0v.search0104.3.17.20917b74ud2gep&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_4_10065_10068_319_317_10696_453_10084_454_10083_10618_10307_10301_537_536_10902_10059_10884_10889_10887_321_322_10915_10103_10914_10911_10910,searchweb201603_51,ppcSwitch_0&algo_expid=4697c4a3-97f8-4aa1-bcd9-314da9bda415-2&algo_pvid=4697c4a3-97f8-4aa1-bcd9-314da9bda415&transAbTest=ae803_4) проигрывать музыку mp3 (просто на наушники), передаваемую с телефона или дополнительно нужен ещё какой-то модуль?
Или [ESP32](https://ru.aliexpress.com/item/ESP-32-ESP-32S-Wi-Fi-Bluetooth-2-4-Micro/32906857429.html?spm=a2g0v.10010108.1000014.2.28974eabvTqlX9&pvid=67fbee98-d8fa-4a13-bef0-14e3efde545b&gps-id=pcDetailBottomMoreOtherSeller&scm=1007.13338.80878.000000000000000&scm-url=1007.13338.80878.000000000000000&scm_id=1007.13338.80878.000000000000000) умеет? Я правильно понимаю, что это программируемый модуль arduino, под который можно написать свой софт под андроид?

Comment: У ESP-12 нет выходов с цифро-аналоговым преобразователем (DAC), поэтому просто средствами самого модуля выводить нормальный аудиосигнал (не писк или жужжание) не получится. У ESP32 выходы с DAC есть, так что выводить звук в принципе можно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это подсемейство устройств ESP8266

ESP-12 это wi-fi модуль и микроконтроллер в одной коробке, вы можете для него написать программу, в arduino ide, но непосредственно к arduino он не имеет отношения. Как собственно и к android. Так же он может выступать в роли wifi-модуля, для arduino или любого другого устройства, способного общаться через rs232. Однако он сам себе микроконтроллер.

В ESP-32 это нафаршированный всем подряд девайс, там уже есть bluetooth, [и другие плюшки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESP32). Но для хранения mp3 памяти все равно не хватит. 
Придется использовать модуль внешней sd карты.
А вот про передачу звука на наушники через bluetooth пока не скажу, сам еще планирую разобраться с этой темой.

Comment: "Но для хранения mp3 памяти все равно не хватит" - мне не надо хранить, нужно проигрывать напрямую с телефона, как простые блютуз-наушники. Вот и сомневаюсь, битрейта хватит ли для воспроизведения более-менее качественного звука

Comment: @ВладимирМалахов а как она их с телефона получит?

Comment: через блютуз. или это невозможно?

Comment: @ВладимирМалахов я не так вас изначально понял, должно получится, но битрейта вряд ди хватит, я перезвоню такое подключение только последовательный порт использовал

Comment: "А вот про передачу звука на наушники через bluetooth пока не скажу, сам еще планирую разобраться с этой темой. " Поделитесь результатами, плз, когда будут.